# How to use PUT method in restangular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, restangular

I am using restangular, but I have a problem with "Put" method, its not working as expected

My angularService code

```
 var userService = function (restangular) {
            var resourceBase = restangular.all("account/");

            restangular.addResponseInterceptor(function (data, operation, what, url, response, deferred) {
                if (operation == "getList") {
                    return response.data;
                }
                return response;
            });
      this.getUserById = function (id) {

                return resourceBase.get(id);
                // return restangular.one("account", id).get();
            };
            this.updateUser = function(user) {
                return user.Put();
            };
}
```

My controller code

```
 var userEditController = function (scope, userService, feedBackFactory, $routeParams) {

        scope.user = undefined;

        scope.updateUser = function () {

            userService.updateUser(scope.user).then(function (data) {
                feedBackFactory.showFeedBack(data);
            }, function (err) {
                feedBackFactory.showFeedBack(err);
            });
        };

        userService.getUserById($routeParams.id).then(function (data) {
            scope.user = data.data;   **// Please not here I am reading the object using service and this object is getting updated and pass again to the service for updating** 

        }, function (er) {

            feedBackFactory.showFeedBack(er);
        });

    };
```

**but I am getting an error "Put" is not a function , I checked the user object and I found that the user object is not restangularized ( no any additional methods found). How can I solve it**

Answer (score 12):

You can only 'put' on a data object.

`customPUT([elem, path, params, headers])` is what you want. use it like this:

```
Restangular.all('yourTargetInSetPath').customPUT({'something': 'hello'}).then(
  function(data) { /** do something **/ },
  function(error) {  /** do some other thing **/ }
);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can have put method only in restangularized objects. To fire put on any object, you need to check for put method, if object does not contain any put method then you need to convert that object in restangularized object.

Change your updateUser to following :

```
 this.updateUser = function(user) {
    if(user.put){
        return user.put();
    } else {
        // you need to convert you object into restangular object
        var remoteItem = Restangular.copy(user);

        // now you can put on remoteItem
        return remoteItem.put();
    }
 };
```

Restangular.copy method will add some extra restangular methods into object. In short, it will convert any object into a restangularized object.

Comment: How'd you let it know that the type is `user`? eg, I get `http://localhost:8100/api/undefined`  when using the `copy()` method. The `undefined` is supposed to be the `user` object. How to make it right? Thanks!